# Sequelize Node: Why is there a difference between the query execution time and actual return time of the function

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, query-optimization

I am using sequelize to connect to my mysql db in the node application. To measure the time taken by the query, i have logged the query execution time using the benchmark and logging options.

```
const Data = await sequelize.query(query, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    benchmark: true,
    logging: (sql, resTime) => logger.info(`${sql} - [Query Execution Time: ${resTime}ms]`)
});
```

Then I measured the execution time of this line using performance.now().

The time difference between them is huge.

For eg:

- Query time: 10ms.  Performance time: 50ms
- Query time: 47ms.  Performance time: 100ms
- Query time: 125ms.  Performance time: 250ms

Is there a particular reason for this time difference and is there anyway i can predict the time difference?

Comment: How many records do you fetch? Does query time and performance time getting closer to each other while a number of records are growing?

Comment: The number of records are static 2M in total. The query i am using is "select comments from user_comments where email = ?". Email is indexed. Based on email the max comments in this list is 54. But my question is why does sequelize take so much time and is there a way to reduce or guess this difference?

Comment: It could be extra time for conversion. Could you indicate a number of records in those three query timings?

Comment: How far apart (geographically) are the client and server?

Comment: @Anatoly The 1st and 2nd one is just 5 records. The third one 30 records.

Comment: @RickJames Probably about 250 miles

Comment: @alantrevor - OK, that might explain a delay of 1ms _per query_, not the large numbers you are experiencing.  Please provide the _generated_ SQL for the query.